# SSRS YTD & MTD Calculation base Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to sum & count for my last year values

I have two parameters in report one is `StartDate`, and 2nd `EndDate`

When I choose these two dates so its showing me values as current, so if I choose `StartDate` - 01/11/2016 and `EndDate` - 10/11/2016 so I want to compare 01/11/2015 - 10/11/2015 values so I can compare last years values as well.

So when someone change the parameters dates then it show me last year and current values. I've done current one just struggling last year expression.

Comment: You can get the last year date by using `=Parameters!StartDate.AddYears(-1)` and `=Parameters!EndDate.AddYears(-1)` but if you need to filter your query you will have to create two additionals parameters or get the last year date for each parameter in SQL.

Comment: I dont want to create more two parameters

Comment: I tried your experssion and getting error ADDyears is not a member of Microsoft reporting Services

Comment: Replace StartDate and EndDate by the name of your parameters. Also be sure your parameters are set to date / time type.

Comment: yes that the paramentrs name and its set DAte.time type

Comment: Where are you using that expression?

Comment: =IIF(Parameters!StartDate.AddYears(-1) > Parameters!StartDate.Value, 
Sum(Fields!Number_of_Nights.Value, "Hotel"),NOTHING)